# Can't install eclipse on windows 10

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install the eclipse DE and I'm getting an error in installing it from every download. The error log reads

```
`Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen.
```

I've seen issues with the same error for installing plugins to eclipse but not eclipse itself. Is there any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to official site and download eclipse as zip.

Comment: I've done this but for some reason I end up with the same error